# How to close jquery dialogue box for mobile application

Tags: jquery, mobile

I am doing a site to view in mobile ,i need a popup/dialogue box to display the contents inorder to avoid page redirection.I have used the code

```
<a href="<?=site_url('cart/terms_conditions/'.$cart['Product_ID'])?>"  data-rel="dialog" style="color:#27d9fb; font-size:100%;">Terms & Conditions</a>
```

The dialogue box appeared and it looks good my problem is how can i close the dialogue box .i need to stay in home page when user close the terms& condition page.I have used jquery, javascript

> location.reload(true);

but it won't works. if any body knows it please help.

Ant help will be appeciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not just use: `$('.ui-dialog').dialog('close')`?

eg. add a 'close' button to your terms & conditions page and then trigger `.dialog('close')` when the button is clicked.

```
<button id="close-button">Close</button>

$('#close-button').click(function() {
  $('.ui-dialog').dialog('close');
});
```

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-dialogs.html

Comment: Thank you for your help i have used  data-rel="back"  link attibute and it work thanks alot.